# Implementing third phase called merge after Reduce phase

Tags: hadoop, new-operator, reduce, phase

I need to add a third phase – merge – which combines the outputs of separate, parallel Reduce tasks.This makes it possible to do things like joins and build cartesian products.Can anyone help me how to do it??I checked there is no Hadoop 0.21 API to support his function.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop is a MapReduce (not MapReduceMerge!) framework and this is not likely to change. That said, you could file a Jira or ask at http://getsatisfaction.com/cloudera/ to get the official stand on this.

If you need joins you should try Pig (the only one I have hands-on experience with, but there are others too - Hive,...). Pig makes joins quite simple to do.